# Defining a notion of dimension using the length of maximal prime ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Corrections:

1. The pattern identified in the question is wrong. The core reason is this. $(0)$ is not a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ because $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is **not** an integral domain. For proof, consider $(0x+1y)(1x+0y) = 0x+0y$, so $\mathbb{Z}^2$ has nonzero zero divisors. Nonzero zero divisors, more generally, demonstrate the failure of the complement of $(0)$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ to be multiplicatively closed. The other parts of the setup build on this mistake and infer a pattern that doesn't hold.

---

I was reading about the definition of [the going-up property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going_up_and_going_down) and wondering what chains of prime ideals typically look like.

**Can we use chains of prime ideals to define a notion of dimension? If so, how do we do it?**.

I'll define a maximal chain of prime ideals as a strict ascending chain of prime ideals that cannot be extended into a larger chain, and, additionally, has the longest possible length of any such chain. So, these chains satisfy both a local optimality property and a global one.

I tried looking around for maximal examples in easy to understand rings: $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

The maximal strict chains of prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ look like:

$$ (0) < (p) < (1) $$

A maximal strict chain of prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ looks like the following, where a pair $(a, b)$ will be denoted as a formal sum $ax+by$.

The chain below is written with redundant generators to make the pattern more obvious.

$$ (0, 0) < (0, py) < (0, y) < (qx, y) < (x, y) $$

Let's also note that because multiplication in each dimension is componentwise, every ideal of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ looks like a product of ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$. For example, in the two-dimensional case:

$$ (ax+by, cx+dy) = (a,c)x + (b,d)y $$

This follows by the Chinese Remainder Theorem and the fact that we can freely and independently choose the coordinates of the coefficient of $ax+by$ and likewise for $cx+dy$.

For $\mathbb{Z}^3$ we can come up with a similar chain of length $7$.

**Conceptually, we're laying out chains of ideals for each dimension on top of each other and then subtracting the overlap.**

The ideal $(0)$ is also a bit of an odd duck, since its presence as a prime ideal basically just tells us that we're working with an integral domain.

So, if we tentatively define $D(R)$ where $R$ is a ring as the length of a maximum strict ascending chain of prime ideals that does not contain $(0)$, then we get the following nice formula:

$$ D(\mathbb{Z}^n) = 2n $$

For the field $\mathbb{R}$, we get the even nicer result:

$$ D(\mathbb{R}^n) = n $$

**Is there a real notion of dimension that this is similar to?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can we use chains of prime ideals to define a notion of dimension? If so, how do we do it?.

> I'll define a maximal chain of prime ideals as a strict ascending chain of prime ideals that cannot be extended into a larger chain, and, additionally, has the longest possible length of any such chain.

That length $n$, if it is finite, defines [Krull dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension) of a ring.  It enjoys several sensible properties that you can find in most commutative algebra books.

> So, if we tentatively define $()$
> where $$
> is a ring as the length of a maximum strict ascending chain of prime ideals that does not contain $(0)$
> , then we get the following nice formula: $D(\mathbb{Z}^n) = 2n$

Why would you leave out $\{0\}$ if it's prime? Oh well. Anyhow, $\mathbb Z^n$ still only has Krull dimension $1$ for any $n$. The Krull dimension of a finite product of rings is just the maximum of the rings involved in the product. (See [this for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2613191/29335)). A maximal chain of prime ideals for $n=2$ is given by $\{0\}\times\mathbb Z\subseteq (p)\times \mathbb Z$.  The dimension is given by the number of links: $1$.